# Deleting duplicate elements in a list in c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct, singly-linked-list

I have a task to delete any duplicate elements from a list. I am using a struct and pointers for my functions. Here is the struct and the function:

```
struct node
{
    int key;
    node *next;

}*start = NULL;

int SIZE = 0;
```

Where size increments when an item is added. There is the function for deleting duplicates:

```
void del_dup() 
{
    if (!start) {
        return;
    }
    if (SIZE == 1) {
        return;
    }

    node * pointer = start->next;
    node * prev = start;

    node * mPointer = nullptr;
    node * mPrev = nullptr;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++)
    {
        if (pointer->next) 
        {
            mPointer = pointer->next;
            mPrev = pointer;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= SIZE; j++)
        {
                if (pointer->key == mPointer->key)
                {
                    mPrev->next = mPointer->next;

                    delete mPointer;
                }
                else
                {
                    mPrev = mPointer;
                    mPointer = mPointer->next;
                }
        }
        prev = pointer;
        pointer = pointer->next;
    }
}
```

The thing is I get a crash at the if statement to compare if the two elements match:

```
if (pointer->key == mPointer->key)
```

The error is access violation type and **nullptr** for **mPointer**.

The list is filled from the user every time he runs the program with the values he wants. Here is the push function:

```
void push_start(int n) {
    elem *p = start;
    start = new elem;
    start->key = n;
    start->next = p;
    SIZE++;
}
```

Any help to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks in forward!

Comment: What is the "non-linked list"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I meant not double-linked. I will edit it.

Comment: Why SIZE is not a member of the structure?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Does it make any difference if it is ?

Comment: Is there a strong reason for you to use that data structure and not one of the standard libraries container classes?

Comment: @rollstapewz In this case you can not use more than one list in  program.

Comment: @rollstapewz At least the condition in this if statement for (int j = i + 1; j <= SIZE; j++) is wrong.

Comment: @jotasi Yes there is. It is a homework assignment although I prefer the stl.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yeah, I have to use one list and I am pretty convinced the if statement in the second for loop is wrong and I can't seem to think of a way to write it properly...

Comment: @rollstapewz You should not rely on SIZE because you do not change it in the function when a node is deleted.

Comment: If your list had iterator support you could use `std::unique`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am aware of that but I am not using stl to have a list as an object.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So if I decrement size after successfully deleting an element would this solve the problem? Edit: Tried it and did not help.

Comment: [MCVE] required. Otherwise, we can only guess.

Comment: @rollstapewz Your function is very confusing. You are using confusing names as for example pointer and mPointer

Comment: Create a test list with 2 *equal* elements and 2 *unique* elements and debug your function, I think the problem will come to you pretty quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it is a bad idea to declare the variable `SIZE` outside the structure definition. In this case all functions that deal with the list will suffer from accessing to the global variable. You can not have more than one list in the program.

You could "wrap" the structure node in one more structure as for example

```
struct node
{
    int key;
    node *next;

};

struct list
{
    node *head;
    size_t /*int*/ size;
};
```

In this case each list would have its one data member size.

The function `del_dup` looks very confusing and you are using confusing names as for example `pointer` and `mPointer`. You should not rely on the variable SIZE that shall be decremented when a node is deleted.

I can suggest the following function implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

struct node
{
    int key;
    node *next;
} *head = nullptr;

size_t size;

void push_front( node * &head, int key )
{
    head = new node { key, head };
    ++size;
}

std::ostream & display_list( node * head, std::ostream &os = std::cout  )
{
    os << size << ": ";

    for ( const node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->key << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

void del_dup( node * head )
{
    for ( node *first = head; first; first = first->next )
    {
        for ( node *current = first; current->next;  )
        {
            if ( current->next->key == first->key )
            {
                node *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                delete tmp;
                --size;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 10;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( nullptr ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( head, std::rand() % ( int )N );
    }

    display_list( head ) << std::endl;

    del_dup( head );

    display_list( head ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
10: 2 2 3 3 8 5 6 2 6 1 
6: 2 3 8 5 6 1
```

Comment: Okay, I will try this, thanks a lot. One thing I do not understand is what is the purpose of ostream & ... ?

Comment: @rollstapewz In this case you can write your list for example in a file.

Comment: Yes, but its not necessary ?

Comment: @rollstapewz You can use your function to output the list. it is just a demonstrative program that shows how the function del_dup can be implemented.

Comment: It worked, modified it a bit for my needs. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you're at some point comparing keys with an already deleted node. <del>For example, you're assigning `mPointer = pointer->next`, then possibly deleting `mpointer`, then at the end of the inner loop assigning `pointer = pointer->next`. So wouldn't it be possible for `pointer->next` to have already been deleted there?</del>

## Edit

Acutally it's much more likely that your inner loop condition is the problem. Try just:

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
```

instead.

Comment: pointer = pointer -> next is assigned in the else statement if there is not a deleted element.

Comment: I have tried both conditions and it wont work.

Comment: @rollstapewz You'll probably have to post a complete minimum working example in order to get any actual help here. There's a bunch of stuff it could be. As a piece of advice, if you don't know how to use a debugger, try just adding print statements so you can at least find out the value of `i` and `j` when it crashes

Comment: What do you mean by "complete minimum working example" ? I copied the whole function. In the main thread I am only calling it ? What more than this?

Comment: @rollstapewz well, there's a very lovely article about [minimal examples right here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The gist of it though is that I need to be able to be able to reproduce your error in order to understand it. I assume when you actually run it you have an example list? I would need that. Otherwise random guessing really is the best anyone can do

Comment: I edited it again. Hope it is more understandable right now.